# Sequence of Functions in $L^{p}(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider the following statement :

> [**Lemma**] : Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space. Then any function in $L^{p}(X)$ is the limit in $L^{p}$ of a sequence of simple functions in $L^{p}$.

How can we prove this?

Comment: Are you aware of the famous Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: This is more or less the definition of $L^p$ space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\left(g_{n}\right)$ be an increasing sequence of simple nonnegative functions that converges (pointwise) to $f^{+}$ and let $\left(h_{n}\right)$ be an increasing sequence of of simple nonnegative functions that converges to $f^{-} .$ Let $\varphi_{n}:=g_{n}-h_{n} .$ Then $\varphi_{n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise and :
$$\left|f-\varphi_{n}\right| \leq|f|+\left|\varphi_{n}\right| \leq |f|+h_{n}+g_{n} \leq 2|f| .$$ Thus, $\left|f-\varphi_{n}\right|^{p} \leq 2^{p}|f|^{p} .$ It follows first that $\varphi_{n} \in L^{p}$ and second that $\left\|f-\varphi_{n}\right\|_{p} \rightarrow 0$ by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.